# Unable to print table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to print the data of an object in the form of a table using javascript. The code I have written does not display anything. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Here is the code i wrote-

```
function Movie(id,movieName)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.movieName = movieName;
}

function MoviesWatched()
{
    this.movies = new Array();
}

MoviesWatched.prototype.addMovie = function(id,name)
{
    this.movies[id]=new Movie(id,name);
}
MoviesWatched.prototype.getTable = function()
{
    var movie;
    var table="<table border=1>";
    for(movie in this.movies)
    {
        table += "<tr><td>";
        table += movies[movie].id;
        table += "</td><td>";
        table += movies[movie].name;
        table += "</td></tr>";
    }
table += "</table>";
return table;
}

var myList=new MoviesWatched();

myList.addMovie(1,"Inception");
myList.addMovie(2,"Red");

document.write(myList.getTable());
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a `console.log` on your `myList.getTable()` and see if it's outputting anything?

Comment: I just started learning javascript, I don't know how to do that, can you guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getTable function, you need to change `movies` to `this.movies` and change `name` to `movieName`

```
var movie;
var table="<table border=1>";
for(movie in this.movies)
{
    table += "<tr><td>";
    table += this.movies[movie].id;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += this.movies[movie].movieName;
    table += "</td></tr>";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/9Gzdv/1/